# Haskell module optimization

Tags: haskell, optimization

I have a problem with Haskell module optimization.

There is Main module.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Control.DeepSeq
import Formatting
import Formatting.Clock
import System.Clock

import Data.Array

size :: Int
size = 200 :: Int

stdMult     :: (Ix a, Ix b, Ix c, Num d) =>
               Array (a,b) d -> Array (b,c) d -> Array (a,c) d
stdMult x y =  array resultBounds
                 [((i,j), sum [ x!(i,k) * y!(k,j) | k <- range (lj,uj)])
                                   | i <- range (li,ui),
                                     j <- range (lj',uj') ]
    where ((li,lj),(ui,uj))     = bounds x
          ((li',lj'),(ui',uj')) = bounds y
          resultBounds
            | (lj,uj)==(li',ui') = ((li,lj'),(ui,uj'))
            | otherwise = error "error"


main :: IO ()
main = do
  let a = array ((1,1),(size, size)) [((i,j), 2*i-j) |
                                  i <- range (1,size),
                                  j <- range (1,size)]
  let b = array ((1,1),(size, size)) [((i,j), 2*i+3*j) |
                                  i <- range (1,size)`,
                                  j <- range (1,size)]

  start <- getTime ProcessCPUTime
  let
    c = stdMult a b
  end <- c `deepseq` getTime ProcessCPUTime
  fprint (timeSpecs % "\n") start end
  return()
```

When `stdMult` in Main module, everything works ok. I replace `stdMult` to another module.
When I don't use ghc optimization, execution time is the same.
When I use ghc options -O3, when `stdMult` in Main module time execution decreases, but when `stdMult` in another module, execution time is almost unchanged!
For example, when `stdMult` in Main I have time 3 seconds, and when `stdMult` not in Main I have time 30 seconds, for matrix 500x500.

It is very strange!

Comment: What is `stdMult3`?

Comment: It is `stdMult`. I corrected, thanks.

Comment: What happens when you add `{-# INLINABLE stdMult #-}`?

Comment: Separately, you should generally use `Criterion` for microbenchmarks, rather than trying to roll your own. There are lots of ways to accidentally measure something other than what you think you're measuring.

Comment: @dfeuer thanks for good advice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(You need the `clock` and `formatting` packages from Hackage to compile the code.)

I can reproduce the 10x slowdown when `stdMult` is in a different module.  Luckily a fix is easy: in the module where `stdMult` is defined, add an [`INLINABLE`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#inlinable-pragma) pragma:

```
{-# INLINABLE stdMult #-}
```

It adds the definition to the interface file (`.hi`) which allows inlining in the modules that uses it, which in turn allows it to be specialized to fast machine `Int` instead of slow abstract `Ix` and `Num` polymorphic code.  (If it's in the same module GHC can inline and specialize at will, and things aren't `INLINABLE` by default because it can cause executable code bloat and slower compilation.)

Alternatively to `INLINABLE`, you can manually [`SPECIALIZE`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#specialize-pragma) to the types you want optimized implementations for.  This is a bit more verbose, but should be faster to compile in big projects (it will be specialized once per export, instead of once per import, at a rough guess).

```
{-# SPECIALIZE stdMult :: Array (Int, Int) Int -> Array (Int, Int) Int -> Array (Int, Int) Int #-}
```

Comment: Perhaps "instead of once per import" could be made more precise as "instead of once per imported use" or something like that. If `stdMult` is used 10 times, it will be inlined 10 times, I think, so it can be more that "once per import" (which is still a reasonable rough guess, as you state above).

Comment: @chi, that's not likely true. The specializer works across modules too, and *should* create just one specialization per module per type.

Comment: @dfeuer Interesting. I was perhaps thinking too much about inlining. Thanks.

Comment: @chi, of course, as usual, the best way to be sure is to actually inspect the compiled core. I don't have time to play with that today.